# java - Best way to display object properties

Tags: java, user-interface, reflection, properties, javabeans

Reflection or hashmaps? Suppose you are writting a graphical application where you have objects lying around and users have the posibility of clicking on them. That said, you want to display the clicked object information somehow.

I end up reading `Accessible` interface from accessibility java package and `AccessibleContext` class... Before that, I wrote testing code using hash maps for properties instead of class fields. And lastly, I thought in Reflection after reading that JavaBeans use instrospection.

What would you recommend in such applications?

Comment: I'll take it as accepted, but there was a missunderstanding of needs (maybe was my spelling). Instrospection or Reflection is a good approach when you need to know something about an object when the object is not yet instantiated. But, when you have an object running, and you _know_ that object, probably the best is to call those methods instead. Upon those calls, you could build a "properties table". Anyway, your answer was useful for me, to dig into Commons BeanUtils. Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using reflection and introspection sounds like a better approach than using HashMaps. Instead of using this API directly, I would recommend an abstraction layer like [Commons BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/), which will allow you to work with classes adhering to the JavaBean standard in an easy manner.

Here's the [User Guide](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/package-summary.html#package_description) complete with examples.

Comment: I'm on it. I have the same opinion about HashMaps for two main reasons: Obfuscates the code and increases the use of memory. And, `AccessibleContext` seems to be much more specific although Java API documentation insists on implementing the package interfaces.

Comment: There's still something missing. As you can see, I mentioned `Reflection` for a runtime program. That's because the need of representing a list of properties avoiding writting the correspondent getter/setter. That's also why I thought in having a `HashMap` iterating with its values.I read the User Guide but I didn't find any functionality that suits the need of "get all the properties I want to represent graphically" (note that it's not the same as "get all the object properties).I know that not follow JavaBean spec is enough for a property not being found, but still seems not fitting my needs

Comment: avoiding the netiquette as I need more characters, I don't see why wasting a line for invoking a method using `Reflection` should be different from invoking the method itself. Remember that we are at run-time. The main idea holds in getting a set of properties that could be represented, e.g., `myObject.getProperties()` implemented by the object (sort of java `Properties`). I'm looking for the best way of solving that.

Comment: Just to note something, After re-reading my question I think you missunderstood the idea. I'm not refering to apps like GUI builders and so on. Think of a drawing tool (in fact, thats my app objetive) or a math tool that when you click/step-over/interact with, for example, a 2D point you get its coordinates, if it's visible, etc, in a classic table label-value style.

Comment: anyway thanks for pointing me that out. I have found that `java.beans.BeanInfo` defines [`getPropertyDescriptors()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/beans/BeanInfo.html#getPropertyDescriptors%28%29). That should be useful.